# GitLab CI/CD and building on Mac Mini with M1 Processor - Provision Profile

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, macos, ios

### I [followed](https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/setup-a-flutter-ci-cd-with-gitlab-ci-part-1-8d40b7a3b3dc) a guide

to setup a simple GitLab runner on my 2020 mac Mini with an M1 processor. **Everything builds great except for iOS.**

## My error:

```
Xcode build done.                                           33.0s
Built /Users/directories/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app.
$ cd ios
$ xcodebuild clean archive -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -archivePath RunnerArchive
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild clean archive -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -archivePath RunnerArchive
User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/directories/ios/RunnerArchive
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.company.app" doesn't include the currently selected device "my Mac mini" (identifier 11111111-111-1111-1111-11111111). (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

If I use `flutter build ios` *from the command line, and even distribute with Xcode's GUI (no modifications), **everything works fine**.*

I noticed this [post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668952) about changing the xcodebuild destination, but I'm not sure how to approach this with flutter.

## Here's my gitlab-ci.yml.

```
stages:
##  - test # All jobs related for testing such as Unit Test
#  - builda
  - buildi

#flutter_test: # Name of the lane
#  stage: test # type of stage
#  script:
#    - flutter test # Run Flutter test
#  tags:
#    - flutter # Tags for runner


#flutter_build_android: #Job name
#  stage: builda # kind of job
#  before_script:
#    - flutter packages get
#    - flutter clean
#  script:
#     - flutter build apk
#  artifacts:
#    paths:
#      - build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
#  tags:
#    - flutter

flutter_build_ios:
  stage: buildi
  before_script:
    - flutter packages get
    - flutter clean
  script:
    - flutter build ios
    - cd ios
    - xcodebuild clean archive -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -archivePath RunnerArchive
    - xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath RunnerArchive.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptions.plist -exportPath ./build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ios/build/Runner.ipa
  tags:
    - flutter
```

## flutter doctor. jic:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-18.0.pre.211, on macOS 11.2 20D64 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-18.0.pre.211 at /Users/User/Dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 643e65984a (7 hours ago), 2021-02-05 08:58:31 -0800
    • Engine revision b04955656c
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-0.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/User/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0
```

It seems to be acting as though I'm trying to run the app on my Mac? Is that correct? *Why should it care?*

**I'm not sure one issue starts an another begins here**. I understand if I have posted in the wrong place. Thanks to anyone with anything to offer.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change the distribution type. Thanks!